# Jacobson radical of an Artinian ring is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> **Definition**: For a ring with unit $R$, Jacobson Radical is defined as the ideal $J(R) = \{r \in R: rM = 0 \}$ where $M$ is simple.

How do I show the $J(R)$ is nilpotent for an Artinian ring $R$?

[A similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871063/nilpotent-jacobson-radical), but it uses Nakayama, which assumes commutativity. The only lead I got is forming a chain of inclusion $J^n \supset J^{n+1} \supset \dots$ and this chain terminates with $J^{n} = J^{n+k}$ for every $k \geq 1$

Comment: I explicitly said in that solution that I’m using a version of Nakayama’s lemma that is valid for noncommutative rings, and I spell it out.  So, you are not reading it correctly...

Comment: But how do I know it is also finitely generated to apply Nakayama? Mine isn't a finite dimensional algebra

Comment: Artinian implies Noetherian, so all right ideals are finitely generated.

Comment: Isn't that only when the Artinian Ring is commutative?

Comment: Nope. Right Artinian implies right Noetherian in a ring with identity. Always.  I guess we have a problem if you want to use the fact we’re working on to prove that theorem, though.

Comment: yeah so I read that theorem and it is by Hopkins, but it uses this result. But that investigation also led me to a proof that doesn't use Nakayama.

Comment: ok. You’ve got me thinking I should add a different proof. Or you can!